# Get website image info/metadata

Tags: image, powershell, metadata

So I have scoured google for mention of anybody trying to use powershell to get information about files from a URL/URI but with no luck. I have found ways to get metadata of files from a local source but nothing for an image hosted on a website.

What I want to do:

I have a list of image URL's eg. `www.website/images/img.jpg` and want to grab the metadata without having to download the entire image. I would then store and export this info to a csv to look over later.

So far my code has been resigned to `System.Net.Webclient.DownloadFile()` and then operating on them locally. Is it possible to do this remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're referring to EXIF metadata. Those are embedded in the file, so unless the remote host provides an API that exposes this information you must download the file to be able to read the information.

Judging from what I gleaned from the standard the information is stored at the beginning of the file, so you could try to download just the first couple hundred bytes. However, the size of the EXIF header doesn't seem to be fixed, so you'll want to retrieve a large enough chunk. Also, standard EXIF parsers might not work on incomplete images, so you might need to write your own parser.

All in all I'd say downloading the entire file and extracting the information with standard tools is your best option.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much about the header sizes. My only hope was that because all the images are generated from the same source (and as jpg's) that I would be able to get the headers.

Really seems that just getting the files locally is my best bet.